# Immediate window multi instruction

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to initialize an object **"myObject"** in debug mode from immediate window,

The problem is : **"myObject"** contains a lot of properties and each time i have to initialize those properties from immediate window **one by one** and it is a bit tiring

Is there a way to execute all those instructions at the same time from immediate window

PS : -I dont have the right to modifiy the code in order to initiliaze those properties from there
-I am using VS2010